# I am getting the following exception while launching face book using chrome browser in Selenium can any one suggest me the solution for this

Tags: selenium-webdriver

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path
>   to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver
>   system property; for more information, see
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest
>   version can be downloaded from
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html     at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$0(ChromeDriverService.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:116)
>     at New.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:16)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this code to set the location of chromedriver before initializing the driver. Use the method `setProperty(String key, String path)`:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/tpt/chromedriver.exe");
```